# Is using inline-block for table with dynamic columns feasible?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Ive been toying with a pure-CSS way to create a table without needing to specify the number of columns.  A table where, when the browser is resized the number of rows and columns adjust accordingly.  This code works for the most part:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.kw1 {background-color:#F00; color:#FFF; border-radius:5px; padding:3px;}
.kw2 {background-color:#0F0; color:#000; border-radius:5px; padding:3px;}
.kw3 {background-color:#DDD; color:#000; border-radius:5px; padding:3px;}
.kw4 {background-color:#000; color:#FFF; border-radius:5px; padding:3px;}
.kw5 {background-color:#00F; color:#FFF; border-radius:5px; padding:3px;}
.out {display:inline-block; border:solid 1px #999; width:245px; height:300px; }
img  {width:240px;}    /* image height will vary */
font {font-size:8pt;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="border:solid 3px #000;" >
<span class="out">
    <a href="some-location"><img src="some-image"></a><br/>
    <font class="kw1">keyword 1</font>
    <font class="kw2">keyword 2</font>
    <font class="kw3">keyword 3</font>
    </span>
<span class="out">
    <a href="some-location"><img src="some-image"></a><br/>
    <font class="kw4">keyword 4</font>
    </span>
<span class="out">
    <a href="some-location"><img src="some-image"></a><br/>
    <font class="kw3">keyword 3</font>
    </span>
<span class="out">
    <a href="some-location"><img src="some-image"></a><br/>
    <font class=""></font>
    </span>
<span class="out">
    <a href="some-location"><img src="some-image"></a><br/>
    <font class="kw5">keyword 5</font>
    <font class="kw3">keyword 3</font>
    </span>
</div>
</body>
```

[smaller browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNhE4.png) -- [larger browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/136q6.png)

The problem is the staggered alignment of the "cells"; especially noticeable when real images with varying heights are thrown in.  I thought that specifying an exact height would correct the problem, it has not.

I tried toying with `display:grid` but unless I specified what row and column, items would overflow.

Im open to other pure-CSS ideas, but would love to **NOT** have to specify columns.  Future plans will be inserting new items in between existing ones, I dont want to be adjusting rows and columns all the time.

Comment: `font` is an obsolete element and should not be used

Comment: Did you try flexbox?

Comment: Looks at examples, but could not find a good example of how it was used.

Comment: "A table where, when the browser is resized the number of rows and columns adjust accordingly." — That doesn't sound like a table at all. A table is a data structure with semantics that say everything in a given row has something in common and everything in a given column has something in common. If elements can move into different rows and columns for purely aesthetic reasons then its a grid, not a table.

Comment: the best method is to use bootstrap grid functionality here which can be resized according to your needs, table doesn't fit your purpose.

Comment: @Quentin understood.  I suppose you could say Im mixing my terminology.
@Paulie_D found a good flexbox example site -- yes, I believe `flexbox` is a good fit for me.
@VR7 ... say what now?  Never heard of "bootstrap grid functionality", is that different from `flexbox` or `grid`?  Thanks.

Comment: Looked at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/ -- that looks a lot more complex that just `flexbox`.  But thanks anyway, VR7.

Comment: Bootstrap is pretty awful, and bootstrap 3 is obsolete. Bootstrap 4 uses Flexbox.

Comment: well , as far as I know almost every website uses libraries like bootstrap or materialize to make their sites responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.kw1 {background-color:#F00; color:#FFF; border-radius:5px; padding:3px;}
.kw2 {background-color:#0F0; color:#000; border-radius:5px; padding:3px;}
.kw3 {background-color:#DDD; color:#000; border-radius:5px; padding:3px;}
.kw4 {background-color:#000; color:#FFF; border-radius:5px; padding:3px;}
.kw5 {background-color:#00F; color:#FFF; border-radius:5px; padding:3px;}
.out {
  display:inline-block; border:solid 1px #999; width:245px;height:400px; }
img  {
  width:240px;
  height:300px;
  }    /* image height will vary */
font {font-size:8pt;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="border:solid 3px #000;" >
<span class="out">
    <a href="some-location"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/300x400"></a><br/>
    <font class="kw1">keyword 1</font>
    <font class="kw2">keyword 2</font>
    <font class="kw3">keyword 3</font>
    </span>
<span class="out">
    <a href="some-location"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik"></a><br/>
    <font class="kw4">keyword 4</font>
    </span>
<span class="out">
    <a href="some-location"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/500x600"></a><br/>
    <font class="kw3">keyword 3</font>
    </span>
<span class="out">
    <a href="some-location"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik"></a><br/>
    <font class="kw3">keyword 3</font>
    </span>
<span class="out">
    <a href="some-location"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik"></a><br/>
    <font class="kw5">keyword 5</font>
    <font class="kw3">keyword 3</font>
    </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to define the height of the image otherwise it will cause problems in most cases.
here I have used images of different sizes but they fit in the specific width and height because we have defined it, if you don't give specific height and width then it will automatically take the width and height as per their needs and that will cause problems in alignment.

Comment: Thanks for the code.  *While this does answer my question*, I found using `display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap:wrap;` on the `<div>` allows me to **not** have to specify an image height as well, thus preserving the image ratio.